# Mamzerim and Sifrei Torah

Tags: safrus, mamzer

In the Keset haSofer (1:ד) R' Ganzfried mentions that some hold that a Torah written by a mamzer is passul. In the Lishkat haSofer (ad loc.) he brings that most hold that there is no problem for a mamzer to write tefillin and mezuzot. However, the Bi'urei haSofer (part of R' Yaakov Meir Stern's definitive Sefer Mishnat haSofer) mentions that according to many opinions, a mamzer cannot be mekadesh haShem, making them incapable of writing any sta"m.

All of this seems very confusing to my chevruta and me. Now, a few hours after having learned the above, I have the following questions:

1. Who permits a mamzer to serve as a sofer?
2. If the mamzer is incapable of sanctifying Hashem's name, how can he write tefillin and mezuzot, per the Lishkat haSofer?
3. Why can't a mamzer be mekadesh haShem?

Comment: IIRC this all grew out of a single version of a tosefta of dubious veracity.

Comment: See https://www.sefaria.org.il/Arukh_HaShulchan%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.281.11?vhe=Arukh_HaShulchan,_Yoreh_De%27ah_--_Wikisource&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en to backup DoubleAA's claim.

Comment: See https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.281.4?vhe=Torat_Emet_357&lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en for other opinions and other reasons for forbidding it.